# It's dangerous to use an assignment because the previous value is invalid

Tags: c++

Is it dangerous to use an assignment on uninitialized data?

When should I take extra care when using an assignment operator?

The reason why I am asking is because I was watching the video [C++ and Beyond 2012: Andrei Alexandrescu - Systematic Error Handling in C++](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Andrei-Alexandrescu-Systematic-Error-Handling-in-C) where he shows the `Expected<T>` class which has either a value or an exception. The move constructor is defined as

```
Expected(Expected&& rhs) : .. {
    if (gotHam) new(&ham) T(std::move(rhs.ham));
    ...
```

where `ham` is defined as

```
union {
    T ham;
    std::exception_ptr spam;
};
```

He explains the resoning behind using placement new and at 28:49 he says that since he is using a union he has to take extra care to manage initialization. He then further states at 29:14 that:

> I couldn't use an assignment because assignment assumes that the
>   previous value was valid

I don't understand this - why would an assignment require the previous value to be valid? I would compare it to something like this:

```
int i; // unassigned, i.e. not valid
i = 0; // so this would thus be dangerous?
```

I am thinking that maybe it has to do with the union and that the *class* is uninitialized, but I still do not see the harm in the assignment. Why would an assignment care about the previous value?

Comment: Think in terms of T being a class that manages memory, but the constructor has never been executed.

Comment: @RichardHodges good point - my understand was that an operator= would create that data, similar to how a constructor does it. But I guess that the operator= might *assume* that those constructs have been created by a previous constructor and thus skip that step. Am I on the right track? :)

Comment: A union assumes nothing. It's just memory. How you initialise and use that memory is up to you. This is why Andrei's example has a flag - to tell the surrounding code which member is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What he means is that constructor for T never ran. And thus you can not use ham object in any way. Having it in a union like that is the only way I know of to formally have a usable named object without it's constructor being ran.

This is why I do not believe unions have any place in C++ programs.

Comment: what I don't understand is how the operator= is "using" the object. Doesn't an operator= work similar as a constructor i.e. it assigns data to the object?

Comment: No. Operator= is an assignment operator, which uses already constructed object.

Comment: @Default, the operator that works similar to a constructor is the copy constructor, not the assignment operator.

Comment: so the danger lies in using already existing data in T which has been created by some constructor. I think I get it.

Comment: Thanks for also pointing out that it is only union creating these scenarios.